# Adding Class to SVG

Tags: css, svg

I grabbed an SVG file, [a map of NY State](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Map_of_New_York_County_Outlines.svg), and would like to add classes to various elements (the counties).

I tried adding a class via javascript. The class was added but visually nothing happened. I tried inserting the class directly. That didn't work. I tried adding a fill to an existing ID  but that didn't do anything.

The existing code looks something like:

```
<polygon id="St_Lawrence" class="highlight" points="404.480957,7.098633
```

As said I tried adding a class, adding fill information to the existing ID (St_Lawrence) but that didn't work. However adding a style inline worked (see below)

```
<polygon id="St_Lawrence" style="fill:#FF0000;" points="404.480957,7.098633
```

That, unfortunately, doesn't really help.

The basic code is below:

```
<svg xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     width="633.475098" height="475.573242" viewBox="0 0 633.475098 475.573242"
     style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 633.475098 475.573242" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Layer_1">
            <g fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25">
                <polygon id="St_Lawrence" points="404.480957,7.098633 404.581543,7.098633 404.581543,7.098633 
                    406.171387,7.099609 406.171387,7.099609 406.218262,7.109375 406.218262,7.109375 406.313965,7.109375 408.001465,7.123047 
                    408.001465,7.123047 408.050293,7.123047 408.050293,7.123047 410.122559,7.138672 410.591309,11.53125 410.591309,11.53125
```

**EDIT:**

I worked with another SVG file and got classes to work as they should. Don't know  SVG well enough to decipher why this one works while the first one doesn't.

Comment: not sure what the issue is. It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vry4e8w2/2/

I have a feeling something is wrong with related code, but the svg isn't necessarily to blame. Can't say without seeing your full code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS styles (whether based on class, id, or some other CSS selector) in SVG. It's a little tricky to mix inline attributes (such as individual `fill="blue"`), the `style` attribute (e.g. `style="fill: blue;"`), and stylesheets, because SVG doesn't interpret them in the order of precedence you might expect (or at least, I expect).

In the above map, `id`-based selectors are probably going to be more convenient, because the counties are named by `id`.

Here's an example of CSS styling by id:

```
<svg  xmlns="&ns_svg;" xmlns:xlink="&ns_xlink;" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 width="633.475098" height="475.573242" viewBox="0 0 633.475098 475.573242"
 style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 633.475098 475.573242" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000044;stroke-width:0.5;}
    #St_Lawrence {
        fill: blue; fill-opacity: 0.3;
    }
    #Queens { 
        fill: orange; fill-opacity: 0.9;
    }

]]>
</style>
```

(with the rest of the document the same)

This highlights the two counties with fill colors:

[image: example]

Comment: This answer could be improved my mentioning CSS specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000044;stroke-width:0.5;}
    .highlight{fill:#00ff00;stroke:#000044;stroke-width:0.5;}
]]>
</style>

<g fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25">
    <polygon id="St_Lawrence" class="highlight" points="404.480957,7.098633
```

However, `<polygon>` already has a `class="st0"` which has a `fill:#FFFFFF`, so you probably want to change or remove the `st0` class.

As a test you could just add `.st0:hover{fill:red;}` which will highlight the county when the mouse is moved over it:

```
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25;}
    .st0:hover{fill:red;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000044;stroke-width:0.5;}
]]>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the style to the icon enclosed in the `<path>` tag: `style="stroke:var(--button-bg-color)"`

```
<svg width="32" height="62" viewBox="0 0 32 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M25 37L31 31C31 31 27.3431 27.3431 25 25" style="stroke:var(--button-bg-color)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path d="M31 61C14.4315 61 1 47.5685 1 31C1 14.4315 14.4315 1 31 1" stroke="#C4C4C4"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I need to apply the style to the icon enclosed in the <path> tag: style="stroke:var(--button-bg-color)"

Comment: Hi Евгений Горелов. Please delete all other posts and comments by you on this page and [edit] this one into an answer according to [answer] - or delete it too, if you cannot actually answer the question at the top of this page.